# Spring-Context 4.0 XSD property-placeholder not working

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jdbctemplate

I have the following property in my ApplicationContext.xml. It should load the file from the classpath with the appended System.getProperty("Environment") value.

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:MyConfigFile-${ENVIRONMENT}.properties"/>
```

This works when my Spring-context schema is:

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
```

but not when it is set to:

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
```

Or set to:

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
```

I've replaced the variable values in the following with the values from my config file and everything works fine with the 4.0 schema.

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-    method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${url}"/>
        <property name="user" value="${username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${password}"/>
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="15"/>
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="5"/>
</bean>
```

Any Suggestions?

**edited**
I get the following exceptions:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:388)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:468)
at my.package.namesAPP.dao.APPParams.setAPPDBParmeters(APPParams.java:37)
at my.package.namesAPP.dao.APPParams.getAPPDBParameters(APPParams.java:31)
at my.package.namesAPP.controller.InterceptorController.preHandle(InterceptorController.java:68)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExecutionChain.applyPreHandle(HandlerExecutionChain.java:130)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:932)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:738)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:551)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:568)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1111)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:478)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:183)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1045)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:199)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:109)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:462)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:279)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:232)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:534)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:607)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:536)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:106)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:677)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:128)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77)
... 33 more

Caused by: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.CannotAcquireResourceException: A ResourcePool could not acquire a resource from its primary factory or source.
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1406)
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:594)
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:514)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutAndMarkConnectionInUse(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:743)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:670)
... 36 more
```

Comment: And where do you set ENVIRONMENT? MyConfigFile is inside a jar?

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what does this mean? It's throwing an exception?

Comment: updated with Exception

Comment: ENVIRONMENT is set as a -D option when the servers starts.